# django - make sure one related object is created, race condition

Tags: django, database, object, race-condition

I have a table with a foreign key. (I deliberately use foreign key here and not one-to-one).
I have an Order model:

```
class Order:
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  # more fields..
```

And I want that **only** one instance of this model will exist per user.

I have a simple form (and view) that saves it. And I have this code:

```
try:
   instance = Order.objects.get(user=user)
except Order.DoesNotExist:
   instance = None
form = OrderForm(instance=instance)
```

But I noticed that if the client fire two consequent request at the same time (noticed that as I use ajax), then two instances might get created, despite my the following validation (which suppose to update the existing one).

This is very important as my other code expect only one instance of this model per user. How can I enforce that in django? I've tried the following on my view:

```
@method_decorator(transaction.atomic, name='dispatch')
```

But didn't work.
And as I've said, I can't use One-to-one field here.

Comment: Do you use Django REST Framework? I think you could achieve this with serializer validation

Comment: Unfortunately I dont

Comment: if you have one to one - use OneToOneField, use Order.objects.get_or_create(), to be sure 100% you shoud use locks (`select_for_update()`)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update]

Comment: How can I use select_for_update() with form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may enforce unicity at the database level with `unique_together` and a nullable field:

```
class Order:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    active = models.NullBooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'active'), )
```

The trick is to set `active` to `None` instead of `False` for inactive orders. As `NULL` values are not considered equal at the database level, a user may have multiple inactive orders but only one active one.

Comment: This won't work since user can have more than one inactive order

Comment: This does solve the problem.  I still hope to see if you can find any "code"  constraint check, i.e maybe lock all records in this table which belong to a foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You can set `unique=true` for user. That will ensure only one order per user.

```
class Order:
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=true)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: This is same as setting One-to-one field. And as I've said I can't use it. The reason is the 'active' field. The user is only allowed to have one active, but multiple 'inactive'. That's why I cant enforce it at database level - I would prefer that. I need a transaction or lock based solution, and couldn't find something that works